# Hiding a spaceship on planet/in a town

Tags: spaceships, concealment

My story is going to be a space western, the planet they're on is on the verge of environmental collapse. A town is intending to use a spaceship to reach orbit to join the evacuation efforts, but there is a narrow launch window and a bad guy bearing down on them.

Part of the plot of keeping the villain back would be his inability to actually find the ship.

So the town itself would be a mining town in a box canyon that backs up to a cliff. I thought about putting it in the mine itself, allowing me to blow up the town, eventually. Other options would be in the town's lake, or under the school

As for the ship itself, I don't imagine it as anything fancy, just an ad-hoc freight hauler designed to carry about a hundred people. For the plot, it simply has to get them into orbit where they'll be taken care of.

Comment: How large is this ship, and how durable is it? What kind of technology do the townspeople have?

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 5):

A few ideas:

**The 'town' is the spaceship.** The Bad Guy can search all the huts he wants, without realising the town itself is the spaceship. This idea was in [Dr Who State of Decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_Decay), in which the castle itself was actually a spaceship with ancient vampires living inside.

**The spaceship is underground.** The spaceship could be built in tunnels, with the Bad Guy not having a clue. This seems to make sense as it is a mining town. Concealing the effort could be similar to a more technological version of [The Great Escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalag_Luft_III#Great_escape).

**The spaceship is concealed.** Perhaps the spaceship uses technology the Bad Guy doesn't know exist, such as being visually invisible (ie. cloaked). Or perhaps it looks like a rock on the side of a canyon (much like [Camouflage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camouflage)).

**The Bad Guy is outwitted.** All of the above require deception, and perhaps another form of deception is to outwit the Bad Guy. This could include:

- Make the Bad Guy think he found a ship, but the real one is located elsewhere and the one he discovers is just a decoy.
- Alter the perceptive ability of the Bad Guy. For instance, drug him and let him wake up later. Or distract the Bad Guy from his mission. Or make the Bad Guy a better offer. Or dull his senses such that he cannot think clearly.
- Let the Bad Guy think he is thorough in checking for spaceships, without realising the spaceship is in plain sight (much like the [Stealing Wheelbarrow story](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/wheel-of-fortune/)) and he just doesn't realise it.

Answer (score 4):

The lake is a decent choice because there is some reasonable excuses for it being in there.

1. Since the ship is an ad-hoc creation, they may be testing that it is airtight.
2. If the ship is propelled by rocket fuel, they may be using the deep cold water as protection from fuel evaporation or ignition.

As an added bonus, you can stage a surprise escape by having the townsfolk modify their mining breathing apparatus to let them breath underwater while swimming down to the ship's airlock.

Answer (score 1):

**Water Tower**

The spaceship may be disguised as a water tower or hidden within one.

Here is an image of the Hyllie water tower outside Malmö, Sweden. I'm sure you can see how it could be a disguised spaceship:
[image]

Of similar design: The Haukilahti water tower in Finland:
[image]

And another one from Horsens, Denmark:
[image]

This water tower in Tonwell, UK, could be a launch silo for a spaceship:
[image]

This water tower in Trelleborg, Sweden, is a good example of a spaceship disguised as a water tower.
[image]

Old, overgrown water towerin Sofia,Bulgaria. No one would suspect it of hiding a spaceship.
[enter link description here](https://i.redd.it/5ann4fp01gb01.jpg)

Water tower in Saarland, Germany. Also an obvious hiding place for a spaceship:
[image]

Kaliningrad water tower. Note the disguised booster on the side.
[image]

Nienburg water tower could hide a fair-sized spaceship:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how E.E. "Doc" Smith handled the problem 80 years ago in [*Gray Lensman*](https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/smithee-graylensman/smithee-graylensman-00-h.html) (1939 serial, 1951 novel).

This is one of the greatest examples of classic 1930s pulp. It's completely over the top and a whole lot of fun.

Chapter 10:

> Through Bominger, the Radeligian Big Shot, Kinnison had had a long and eminently satisfactory interview with Prellin, the regional director of all surviving Boskonian activities. Thus he knew where he was, even to the street address, and knew the name of the firm which was his alias--Ethan D. Wembleson and Sons, Inc., 4627 Boulevard Dezalies, Cominoche, Quadrant Eight, Bronseca. That name had been his first shock, for that firm was one of the largest and most conservative houses in galactic trade; one having an unquestioned AAA-1 rating in every mercantile index.

Chapter 19:

> "You noticed the shape of their screens?"
>
> "Roughly cylindrical," in surprise. "They're hiding a lot of stuff, of course, but they can't possibly...."
>
> "I'm afraid that they can, and will. I've been checking up on the building. Ten years old. Plans and permits QX except for the fact that nobody knows whether or not the building resembles the plans in any way."
>
> "Klono's whiskers!" Kinnison was aghast, his mind was racing. "How could that be, chief? Inspections--builders--contractors--workmen?"
>
> "The city inspector who had the job came into money later, retired, and nobody had seen him since. Nobody can locate a single builder or workman who saw it constructed. No competent inspector has been in it since. Cominoche is lax--all cities are, for that matter--with an outfit as big as Wembleson's, who carries its own insurance, does its own inspecting, and won't allow outside interference. Wembleson's isn't alone in that attitude--they're not all zwilniks, either."
>
> "You think it's really fortified, then?"
>
> "Sure of it. That's why we ordered a gradual, but complete, evacuation of the city, beginning a couple of months ago."

...

> Hence, as the Patrol's land forces ground dangerously into position the enemy made no demonstration. The mobile screens were in place, surrounding the doomed section with a wall of force to protect the rest of the city from the hellish energies so soon to be unleashed. The heavy caterpillars, mounting projectors quite comparable in size and power with the warships' own--weapons similar in purpose and function to the railway-carriage coast-defense guns of an earlier day--were likewise ready. Far back of the line, but still too close, as they were to discover later, heavily armored men crouched at their remote controls behind their shields; barriers both of hard-driven, immaterial fields of force and of solid, grounded, ultra-refrigerated walls of the most refractory materials possible of fabrication. In the sky hung the maulers, poised stolidly upon the towering pillars of flame erupting from their under-jets.
>
> Cominoche, Bronseca's capital city, witnessed then what no one there present had ever expected to see; the warfare designed for the illimitable reaches of empty space being waged in the very heart of its business district!
>
> For Port Admiral Haynes had directed the investment of this minor stronghold almost as though it were a regulation base, and with reason. He knew that from their coigns of vantage afar four separate Boskonian observers were looking on, charged with the responsibility of recording and reporting everything that transpired, and he wanted that report to be complete and conclusive. He wanted Boskone, whoever and wherever he might be, to know that when the Galactic Patrol started a thing it finished it; that the mailed fist of Civilization would not spare an enemy base simply because it was so located within one of humanity's cities that its destruction must inevitably result in severe property damage. Indeed, the Port Admiral had massed there thrice the force necessary, specifically and purposely to drive that message home.

...

> And none too soon. Deliberately, grandly the Colossus was leaning over, bowing in stately fashion toward the awful lake in which it stood. But only so far. Then there was a flash, visible even in the inferno of energies already there at war, and the already coruscant lava was hurled to all points of the compass as the full-blast drive of a super-dreadnought was cut loose beneath its surface!
>
> To the eye the thing simply and instantly disappeared; but not to the ultra-vision of the observers' plates, and especially not to the CRX tracers solidly attached by Kinnison and by Henderson. They held, and the chief pilot, already warned, was on the trail as fast as he could punch his keys.
>
> Through atmosphere, through stratosphere, into inter-planetary space flew pursued and pursuer at ever-increasing speed. The Dauntless overtook her proposed victim fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so here an answer.

The ship could disguised as parts of the town. Earlier dismantled to be used as a few buildings in the town, with some items used in everyday stuff like the generators. Only some items would need to be actually hidden, like large thrusters (or find really creative solutions for such things). The town would come together to prepare the ship to be reunited with its parts.

Alternatively it can be just a full mining ship embedded in the rock, around which the town has grown. It seems to have no real way to dislodge itself from the rock, as it wasn't designed to be salvaged after mining. But it does have a freighter build in for moving the stuff off planet, but hasn't been used due to reasons. It is hidden because few or even no one knows of the freighters existence anymore. Or everyone knows and try to hide it for the bad guy.

Both could add to your plot as you can have parts of the story happen with (or even in) the ship in attendance in a certain fashion, making it more integral to the story instead of just a goal to reach.